# Reading several txt files searching for a String with multithreading

Tags: java, string, multithreading, parsing

I have a folder with 100 `.txt` files, 20 or + MB each.
All the files have about `2*10^5 lines of UTF-8 encoded text`.

What is, possibly using multithreading, the fastest way to find which files contain a fixed key string? (The criteria for the contain is the same as the java .contains() function, ie. a normal substring).

There are several ways I found here on SO, but none used `multithreading` (**Why?**), and all of them seem to vary speed depending on the requirements, I cannot seem to understand which of the approaches is better for me.

For example this super-complex approach:

https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/44021/fast-way-of-searching-for-a-string-in-a-text-file

seems to be 2 times slower than a simple line by line search with a `BufferedReader` and the `.contains()` function. How can it be?

And how can I use multithreading to its full potential? The program is run on a very powerful multicore machine.

The output I'm looking for is which files contain the string, and, **possibly**, at which line.

Comment: Multithreading is complicated at the best of times, for most cases, it's simpler to provide a single threaded solution to people so they understand the solution to their problems rather than adding more complexity which might confuse them further, which is the "why". Multithreading also doesn't always give (significant) performance boost, so you need to do some testing to see where the benfits are.  My general suggestion would be to start with [`ExecutorService`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html)

Comment: Maybe even `ThreadPoolExecutor` so you can control the number of active threads better.  This way, you can just dump all the tasks you want to be done into the executor and wait for the results (in one of a number ways)

Comment: Depending on your hardware, scanning of files will not benefit from multi-threading, because the performance bottleneck is the hard disk. But as I said, it depends on the performance of CPU vs Disk. Perhaps 2 or 3 threads woul d scan faster, but 100 threads would likely kill performance entirely.

Comment: If the files are static and you intend to search them many times, then why don't you create an index for them. That will be much faster than scanning them from scratch each time. If they are dynamic then just update the index accordingly based of a file change event. That is what I would look into doing. That is why databases are so great, they index everything and have a query language.

Comment: I was thinking about dividing the files in 8 groups, and parse each group on a different thread (I'm just assuming here, but I guess this is the optimal numbers, because of the cpu's cores (it's Intel i7)). The files are all on the same disk, which is a high end, very fast SSD. I might be completely off though.. I don't know how the disk handles multithreading.

Answer (score 2):

The following code does the job.

It'll get to your directory and look for all the files.
And then will create a new thread for each file and look for target string.

Make sure to **change the path of folder and target String in TheThread class**  as per you need

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;
import java.util.stream.Stream;


//class used for thread
class TheThread implements Runnable {

    int counter = 0;

    //to get stream of paths
    Stream<Path> streamOfFiles = Files.walk(Paths.get("./src/Multi_tasking/Files"));

    //List of total all files in the folder
    List<Path> listOfFiles = streamOfFiles.collect(Collectors.toList());

    //because Files.walk may throw IOException
    public TheThread() throws IOException {
    }


    @Override
    public void run() {

        //increments counter to access the indexes of the list
        counter++;

        //Calling the method for search file at index counter and  target String
        SearchTextInMultipleFilesUsingMultiThreading.lookIn(listOfFiles.get(counter), "target String");
    }
}

public class SearchTextInMultipleFilesUsingMultiThreading {

    //method responsible for searching the target String in file
    public static void lookIn(Path path, String text) {
        try {
            List<String> texts = Files.readAllLines(path);
            boolean flag = false;
            for (int i = 0; i < texts.size(); i++) {
                String str = texts.get(i);
                if (str.contains(text)) {
                    System.out.println("Found \"" + text + "\" in " + path.getFileName() + " at line : " + (i + 1) + " from thread : " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
                    flag = true;
                }
            }
            if (!flag) {
                System.out.println("\"" + text + "\" not found in " + path.getFileName() + " through thread : " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
            }

        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("Error while reading " + path.getFileName());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        //creating object of our thread class
        TheThread theThread = new TheThread();

        //getting the number of files in the folder
        int numberOfFiles = theThread.listOfFiles.size() - 1;

        //if the folder doesn't contain any file at all
        if (numberOfFiles == 0) {
            System.out.println("No file found in the folder");
            System.exit(0);
        }

        //creating the List to store threads
        List<Thread> listOfThreads = new ArrayList<>();

        //keeping required number of threads inside the list
        for (int i = 0; i < numberOfFiles; i++) {
            listOfThreads.add(new Thread(theThread));
        }

        //starting all the threads
        for (Thread thread :
                listOfThreads) {
            thread.start();

        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'll let the answers to other questions speak for themselves, but multithreading is unlikely to be helpful for I/O bound tasks with data stored on a single disk.  Assuming your folder is stored on a single disk, the use case that the disk caches are most optimized for is single threaded access, so that's likely to be the most effective solution.  The reason is because reading the data from disk is likely to be slower than looking through the data once it's loaded into memory, so the disk read is rate limiting.

The simple solution with a BufferedReader and the contains() function may well be the fastest since this is library code that is likely highly optimized.

Now, if your data was sharded onto multiple disks, it might be worthwhile to run multiple threads, depending on how the operating system did disk caching.  If you were going to do multiple searches for different strings, not all known at the time of the first search so that a single pass approach wouldn't work, it might be worthwhile to load all the files into memory and then do multithreaded searches only on memory.  But then your problem isn't really a file search problem any more, but a more general data search problem.

Comment: How about somehow loading all of the files into memory, and then scan with multithreading from there? Free RAM amount is not a problem.

Comment: @LoryA If you're only going to do one search, that approach still involves reading all the data from disk once; you can't get around that.  If you're going to do multiple searches, then that approach might be worthwhile.

Comment: 100 files x 20 MB/file = about 2 GB RAM just to hold the contents, plus what the program needs, plus what Java needs, plus what the rest of the applications running need, including the OS. Divided into shards for processing there could be cache contention with threads breaking locality of reference, and other thread-contention issues. Even with your fast storage hardware, I/O could actually give CPU threads time to work. One thread fetches while another processes. If you set up the read as a producer thread or two, and processing as consumers, that might speed you up.

Comment: @Warren Dew, Reading from the disk once, ok, but between-line reads with my current approach involve the scan with .contains(). So I'm creating a delay between reads.
If I first read it all from disk, and then scanned (.contains()) with multithreading, would I be doing something that makes sense? In that case, would it make sense to divide the files into 8 groups, to take full advantage of the cores?

Comment: @Lew Bloch I didn't understand much of what you said, I'll add some information that might help: the machine has 32GB of DDR4 ram. At the time of execution of this program, about 4 GB are used by the rest of the system. The application is just a super-basic GUI that does this parsing, then exits. The number of files can vary from 40 to a max of 100. The file size can vary from 20 to 22 MB.

Comment: @LoryA Your system almost certainly has a read ahead cache for the disk, either on the disk controller or as part of the OS or both, so you aren't really creating a delay between reads.  If you really want to be sure you could always test it both ways and see.

Comment: @Lory A, How big is the memory allocation for your Java process? The default heap allocation for a Java program is about 1 GB on most platforms; you will need to increase that to hold the 2 GB that 100 files of 20 MB each would require in memory, plus all the other stuff. You will have roughly the same amount of I/O as a striped approach, except that you won't benefit from the on-disk cache, and you won't be able to run CPU-intensive code in one thread while the I/O is happening in another. So you will remove some parallelization with that approach, and require much RAM. Did that help?